# Rally 2.0p5 API: Setting project for rallyiterationcombobox

Tags: javascript, rally

In searching the 2.0p5 documentation, I can't find a way to set the project for the rallyiterationcombobox. Consequently, it's displaying the wrong iterations. As with the rallyteamcombobox, I added a project key/value pair but that appears to be ignored. How do I use the rallyiterationcombobox to select iterations associated with other projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging into the rallyiterationcombobox class, I decided to extend it. I added a single field and now it does what I want.

```
(function ()
{
  var Ext = window.Ext4 || window.Ext;

  Ext.define('Rally.ui.combobox.ProjectIterationComboBox', {
    extend: 'Rally.ui.combobox.IterationComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.rallyprojectiterationcombobox',

    initComponent: function()
    {
      this.config.storeConfig.context.project = this.project;
      this.callParent(arguments);
    },
  });
})();
```